# Geometry of Semi-Simple Lie Groups

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

I wonder, what exactly does it mean for a Lie group to be semi-simple *geometrically*?

I know that any Lie group is a group and a smooth manifold simultaneously, so it can be considered merely as a vector field in dimension one. However, I don't get the geometrical philosophy behind the simplicity of a Lie group. **What does the condition tell us about a vector field associated with the group itself?**

How can one describe *geometrically* the condition of simplicity (or semi-simplicity) of a Lie group?

Answer (score 5):

The sentence "so it can be considered merely as a vector field in dimension one" makes no sense as a manifold is not the same thing as a vector field. There is no single vector field canonically associated with a group. A Lie group is a smooth manifold $G$ equipped with a group operation which happens to be a smooth map $G\times G\to G$, don't read more into it.

For a connected Lie group, Cartan's second criterion says that $G$ is semi-simple if and only if its Killing form $B\colon \mathfrak{g}\times\mathfrak{g}\to\Bbb R$, given by $$B(X,Y) = {\rm tr}({\rm ad}(X){\rm ad}(Y)),$$is non-degenerate. If $G$ is assumed to be compact, then $-B$ is positive-definite and therefore defines a left-invariant Riemannian (Einstein) metric on $G$.

Comment: Well any Lie group admits many left-invariant Riemannian metrics. Just define one at the identity and translate it everywhere. The key thing for a compact group is that the Killing form is a bi-invariant metric. And of course for a non-compact group the Killing form is still bi-invariant, just not positive definite so we get a pseudo-Riemannian metric.

Comment: Rereading my above comment I should clarify: a **semisimple** Lie group has a bi-invariant pseudo-Riemannian metric. We need semisimplicity to ensure non-degeneracy of this metric as Ivo says (I don't believe we need connected though).

Comment: @Callum: There are non-semisimple Lie groups which admit biinvariant pseudo-Riemannian metrics, just these are not defined using the Killing form.

Answer (score 2):

"What exactly does it mean for a Lie group to be semisimple geometrically?" - this can mean many different things depending on the geometric context.
See for example this post (mentioning also Riemannian symmetric spaces)

[What is the intuition behind simple Lie groups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4445808/what-is-the-intuition-behind-simple-lie-groups)

Another particular example is that a semisimple Lie group $G$ does not admit any left-invariant affine structure (whereas a non-semisimple Lie group usually admits one), because for its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ the first cohomology space $H^1(\mathfrak{g},M)$ with any finite-dimensional $\mathfrak{g}$-module $M$ vanishes, by Whitehead's first Lemma.
This is equivalent to some fixed point theorem, for more
see for example [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71723/which-lie-algebra-admit-a-left-symmetric-algebra-structure/178299).

Actually, a connected Lie group $G$ is semisimple if and only if $H^1(\mathfrak{g},M)=0$ for the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$, and for all finite-dimensional $\mathfrak{g}$-modules $M$. This is an algebraic description, but it is also related to Weyl's unitary trick (by Weyl's theorem, which implies the first Whitehead Lemma easily).